# Whats the equivalent of the Linux Alt + '.' on MacOS?

Tags: linux, command-line, osx

I am trying to get the same functionality as on a Linux where the last argument can be inserted into a another command easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `bash` or `zsh`, the shortcut `!$` works in the same fashion.

For example:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ echo "test" >> new_file
[user@localhost ~]$ cat !$
cat new_file
test
```

Comment: Fixed it: it's `!$` -- this is [9.3 History Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction) for bash.